# Click is not working on mat-icon-button using angular

Tags: angular, button, angular6

I am trying to create a sample application using angular 6+. In the application I am reading data from the server and populating a table in which each row has a button to delete that specific row. But the button click is not triggering.

Following is the code for table creation:

```
  <table *ngIf="list.length > 0" mat-table [dataSource]="list" class="">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Id </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i= index"> {{i+1}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Action </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
         <button mat-icon-button (Click)="deleteDevice($event)" type="button" color="primary"  >
            <mat-icon >delete</mat-icon>
          </button>
         </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columndefs"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columndefs;"></tr>
    </table>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  list = [];
  columndefs : any[] = ['id'];
  
  constructor() {
   }
   deleteDevice(event){
     alert("deleteCLicked");
     console.log("cllll");
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Did I miss anything to make the button click to work?

Comment: The problem can be that `(Click)=` should be lowercase: `(click)=`

Comment: If you use VSCode you can install the `Angular Language Service` extension and it would intercept such of typos for you; https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template

Comment: @FaustynPiechowiak yes, that was the issue, thank you for noticing.